# Git control of 'included' projects in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, bitbucket

I have an Android Studio project with two included projects. I make edits to the core 'app' project, and also edits to one of the include projects. All three are under separate GIT control, as the same level (the included projects are not within the 'app' folder). This is a legacy project, so I can't merge into one GIT project.

When I use the Version Control tab to review the edited files, only files from the 'app' project are shown, and none of the files from the edited include is.

Is there anyway to configure Android Studio to show all files that have been edited within the entire project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the other projects as VCS roots in your settings and they will show up. You can even use projects from different VCSs like Subversion and Git.